# Can "a-mingle" be a verb in imperative mood?

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context

In the last lines of "Jingle Bells Rock":

> Jingle bell time is a swell time
>
> To go gliding in a one-horse sleigh
>
> Giddy-up jingle horse, pick up your feet
>
> Jingle around the clock
>
> **Mix** and **a-mingle** in the jingling feet
>
> That's the jingle bell,
>
> That's the jingle bell,
>
> That's the jingle bell rock

Are "mix" and "a-mingle" verbs? If  yes, are they in imperative mood? Who do they refer to? To the horse mentioned one line above?

Comment: "a-mingle" is just a peculiarity of the lyrics to give it a little syncopation, I believe.  The verbs of that line are "mix" and "mingle".  (BTW - the line is "Mix and a-mingle in the jingling *beat*, not feet). :-)

Comment: I've never read the lyrics before, it always sounded like _Mixing and minling_ to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a matter of actual meaning, there is no difference between the "a-" in "Mix and a-mingle" in "Jingle Bell Rock" and the series of "a-" syllables that show up in Bread's "Baby I'm-a Want You" from 1972:

> Baby I'm-a want you
>
> Baby I'm-a need you
>
> You're the only one I care enough to hurt about
>
> Maybe I'm-a crazy

etc., etc.

There would be no loss or gain in coherence if the jingle horse, instead of being directed to "mix and a-mingle," were ordered to "mix and-a mingle"—just as there is no improvement in Bread's lyrics if "I'm-a want," "I'm-a need," "I'm-a crazy," ... were magically transformed into the form "I'm a-want," "I'm a-need," "I'm a-crazy," etc.

The instances of "a-" or "-a" or "-uh-" are there as sound fragments, as Kristina Lopez notes in her comment above—not as a meaningful words to be analyzed. A somewhat subtler example of the same phenomenon appears in Stevie Wonder's "Signed, Sealed, Delivered," where the "-a" at the end of certain phrases could just be an exaggerated catch of breath:

> I've done a lot of foolish things-a
>
> That I really didn't mean-a

But in that case the posted lyrics don't include the audible "-a" sounds.

My advice—besides "Never let yourself  become trapped in an environment where you have to listen to Bread, even for a few seconds, against your will"—is to treat "Jingle Bell Rock" not as a narrative awaiting syntactical analysis, but as a series of aural snowflakes not to be grasped and examined in the clear light of day. And that goes double for "Jingle Bells" by the Barking Dogs.

Comment: In fact, I wouldn’t even consider thinking of the extra syllable in _Jingle Bells_ as being prefixed to _mingle_, rather than suffixed to _and_. Such an _-a_ is exceedingly common in songs specifically after the word _and_ (which is often put right before pauses in the lyrics).